# Minify Json file in Assets on Angular build

Tags: angular, typescript, angularbuild

What is the best way to minify the JSON files on the angular production build?. I have a JSON file in assets folder which is copying to output folder as it is when the production build is done.

In development file will be like [Development file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khMlB.png) and in production the file should be like [Production file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENBYc.png)

Comment: Do you mean compress with something like gzip?

Comment: Edited the question with images

Comment: Hi @BhagavanReddy, welcome to SO, please share you files into code snippets because is better to help you with your problem, see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Hi @jose-lora, Thank you I will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 1):

For now I am doing with post build command which runs the following script

```
import { writeFile, readFile } from 'fs';

readFile('./src/assets/errors.json', (readErr, data) => {
    if (data) {
        var minified = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data));

        writeFile('./www/assets/errors.json', minified, 'utf8', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        return console.log(readErr);
    }
});
```